# Set an alert on Azure from Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: linux, azure, performance, monitoring

So i have three servers in my Log Analytics Workspace and one of them runs Java application, that i can monitor from logs using `perf` command for it's utilisation or it's stats.

Now i want to set an alert if that java service stops.
I want that alert to notify me whenever java service has been stopped from last 30 seconds.

Is there any way i can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

> alert to notify me whenever java service has been stopped from last 30 seconds.
> Is there any way i can achieve that?

Yes, it is possible in Azure Alerts.

Follow the workaround to achieve this.

1. Create an alert in azure monitor for specific app service.
   **Azure Monitor -> Alerts -> Create Alert**
   Select Specific Scope (Your Application) which you want to get alert.
2. After adding scope go to **condition** Tab and select the **signal type** as ***Activity Log***. Then select the signal name as ***Stop Web App***
   [image]
   [image]

After adding the signals create the alert and save it.
Then whenever the web app stops it will trigger the alert.

#### Result

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for replying.
I specifically want to trigger an alert just when the java service stops working on server, i do not have an idea what KQL query should i use to achieve this.

Could you help me with that?